# Removing Duplicates is affecting another macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

We run multiple macros on a worksheet. One of them is used to remove duplicates.

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call Convert_Text_To_Number

    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AE$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

We copy a set of data from one worksheet into our main workbook. This "new" data occupies A2:Z* (I used an asterisk because there is no set limit to the number of rows and we are adding data daily). When we run our comparisons to another data set, we input (manually) new information into columns AA:AE for each completed row. There is a code in place that changes the text color for the entire row to green once a date is inserted into column AE for that respective row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range
Set r = Target.EntireRow

    If Target.row = 1 Then Exit Sub 'don't change header color

    If r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" Then
        r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Else
        r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```

**(The above code is inserted in the Sheet1 object of the workbook)**
After this code was added, each time we run the Remove Duplicates macro, all unique lines that remain are now changed to green text, but there is no date in column AE of that row. I did find that if I go to that cell, hit delete and go to another cell, that row will revert back to black text. Can anyone help me determine what is causing this to occur? It seems like there is a phantom value inserted into the cells.

Comment: That does exactly what it is written to do. It doesn't look at column AE at all; it looks at column AD and running remove duplicates is sufficient to trigger the Worksheet_Change with a **Target** that is many cells, not just one cell. What is the question?

Comment: Well, we copy data into cells that range from columns A to Z. Then we run the remove duplicates. Right after we run that macro, the text changes from black to green for those rows that are left as unique, but there are no values in column AD for those rows yet. So the question is, how is that happening? And I just realized that I meant to state that there is no date in column AD of that row, not AE.

Comment: The worksheet change will only work for the target row. You would need to loop through the range of cells to keep it up to date. So either create a code that loops through column AD or use conditional formatting to change the font color.

Comment: @Davesexcel The problem is, after we run the Remove duplicates and the rows are changed to green text, if I go to the cell in AD for that row and click delete then move out of the cell, the row changes back to black text (as it should). It appears that there is something being inserted in the cells in column AD during the removal process. There are no spaces in that cell, I checked on purpose. I am going to change the code to loop through, but would still like to know where the 'ghost' character is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think that **Target** is a certain individual cell but it is not. It *could* be a single cell but in a remove duplicates command, it is more likely to be rows of cells. You cannot treat a large group of cells like an individual cell by use `Target.EntireRow`.

Example: `Range("A2").EntireRow` is different from `Range("A2:AD50").EntireRow`

The following should point you in the right direction.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rw As Long, rwRng As Range

    For Each rwRng In Target.Rows
        If rwRng.Row > 1 Then
            If Cells(rwRng.Row, 30).Value <> "" Then  'column AD is column 30
                rwRng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            Else
                rwRng.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End If
        End If
    Next rwRng

End Sub
```

Comment: just curious - is there a reason you changed to `.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic`? Is this *better* in some way over `.Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)`?

Comment: If you want to set color to black then do so. If you want to REMOVE color then set to xlautomatic because that is how it starts out.

Comment: yeah - I get that `xlAutomatic` is the same as `RGB(0,0,0)`, but I was just curious if using `xlAutomatic` was in some way faster or more efficient in terms of processing.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. That resolved the issue (which I am still trying to figure out the why part of that). And I was going to ask the same question as Scott.